# Python add list items with condition

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a scenario like this:

```
main = [200,300,400,500]
sec = [0,0,1,0]
new = []
```

The condition is,

1. if element in the second list is equal to 0, then add the element in first list.
   (i.e.) the element in the sec list is 0, so then the element in the main have to be like 500(200+300).
2. if element in the second list is equal to 1,then in the first list place the above element down.
   (i.e.) the element in the first list is 1, so then the element in the main have to the same as previous.

output has to be like,

```
new = [200,500,500,900]
```

Comment: Is the first index always assumed to be as defined in main even if `sec[0]` is `1`? And what if `main[-1]` is declared as `1`?

Comment: Please take a look as enclosure function, that will help

Comment: yeah sec[0] is 1 always

Comment: @antoine What's an enclosure function in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also in your example `sec[0]` is **not** `1`.

Comment: No i mean u just consider that sec[0] as 1, because first element of main[1] remains same in output. i tried using nested loops with if condition but not able to get a breakthrough.

Comment: Something about your input and output doesn't make sense

Comment: new = [200,500,500,900]

Comment: I'm saying the pattern: main = [200,300,400,500], sec = [0,0,1,0] => new = [200, 500, 500, 900]
doesn't make sense

Comment: Do you want new.append(main[i] + main[i - 1]) if sec[i] == 1, or new.append(∑main[0]...main[i]) if 1 or what

Comment: new = [200,500,500,900], new [0] = 200 directly from input, new[1] = [500] because sec [1]= 0 so add main[0] + main [1], new [2] = 500, because sec[2] = 1, so the previous value of output is copied here, new[3] = 900 because sec[3] = 0, so adding main [2] +main[3]

Comment: @Mick for 1 need to paste the previous output from new[], for 0 need to add the values from main list

Comment: Ok, finally I understand

Answer (score 0):

For given conditions and constraints this works fine

```
main = [200,300,400,500]
sec = [0,0,1,0]
new = []

j=0
for i in sec:
    if  i==0 and len(new)!=0:
         new.append(new[-1]+main[j])
         j+=1
    elif i==0 and len(new)==0:
         new.append(main[j])
         j+=1
    elif i==1:
         new.append(new[-1])
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main = [200,300,400,500]
sec = [0,0,1,0]
new = [main[0]]

for i in range(1, len(main)):
    if sec[i]:
        new.append(new[-1])
    else:
        new.append(main[i] + main[i - 1])
        
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
main = [200,300,400,500]
sec = [0,0,1,0]
mem = 0
new = [main[0]]
for idx in range(1,len(main)):
    mem = mem if sec[idx] else sum(main[idx-1: idx+1])
    new.append(mem)
new
[200, 500, 500, 900]
```